# Inventory/Stock Management

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq

I am working on a project where I have Three Table: Inventory, Stock & Purchase. I can only purchase individual products when The quantity in inventory Table is less Than The quantity in stock Table for a particular product. The problem with The following code That blocks purchase for other products Too. Like:

```
Stock Table:
StoreID- ProductID - Quantity
1 - 1- 50

InventoryTable:
StoreID- ProductID - Quantity
1 - 1- 60 //The product is unable To purchase IT has greater quantity regarding The stock Table
1 - 2- 40 //I can purchase This product as
          // This isn't available in stock Table but The following code blocks IT Too
```

I am using a form To submit The demanded products in Purchase Table. So what I need is To match The stock and inventory Table for The individual stock of a product and if IT is less Than min stock Then purchase can be done. I Tried but stuck somewhere. Any idea To do so??

Following is The code I have Tried so far:

```
            SMPURCHASEEntities dc = new SMPURCHASEEntities();

            var con2 = (from s in dc.StoreInventoryDetails
                        select s).ToList();

            string l = Session["EmployeeID"].ToString();
            int g = Convert.ToInt32(l);

            List<EmployeeDetails> con4 = (from r in dc.EmployeeDetails
                                          where r.EmployeeID == (g)
                                          select r).ToList();


            List<Stock> con3 = (from f in dc.Stock
                                select f).ToList();



                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtQuantity.Text.Trim()))
                        {
                            lblMsg.Text = "Fields are empty";
                            return;
                        }

                            SMPURCHASEEntities context = new SMPURCHASEEntities();

                            int d = Convert.ToInt32(Session["EmployeeID"]);


                            List<EmployeeDetails> con = (from m in context.EmployeeDetails
                                                         where m.EmployeeID == (d)
                                                         select m).ToList();


                            List<DemandOrderLine> con_02 = (from c in context.DemandOrderLine
                                                            select c).ToList();



                            DemandOrderLine k = new DemandOrderLine();



                        foreach (StoreInventoryDetails s in con2)
                        {
                            foreach (Stock f in con3)
                            {
                                foreach (EmployeeDetails r in con4)
                                {
                                    if (f.ItemID == s.ItemID && s.Quantity > f.Quantity && f.StoreID == r.StoreID && s.UniTypeID == f.UnitTypeID)
                                    {
                                        Label1.Text = "You have The minimum stock!!";
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                                k.OrderID = Session["OrderID"].ToString();
                                                k.CategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlCategoryID.SelectedValue);
                                                k.ItemID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlItemID.SelectedValue);
                                                k.UnitTypeID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlUnitTypeID.SelectedValue);
                                                k.Quantity = Convert.ToDouble(txtQuantity.Text);
                                                k.Status = 0;
                                                k.ApprovalStatus = Convert.ToBoolean(0);
                                                k.StoreID = r.StoreID;
                                                k.TotalQuantity = Convert.ToDouble(txtQuantity.Text);
                                                k.Dissolved = 0;

                                                try
                                                {
                                                    context.DemandOrderLine.Add(k);
                                                    context.SaveChanges();
                                                }

                                                catch (Exception ex)
                                                {
                                                    ex.ToString();
                                                }
                                            }

                                    }
                                }
                            }
```

Comment: Is ItemId from the code below is ProductId from your table schema above?

Comment: Yes. IT is. Just unable To do The stock matching regarding individual products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check your business rules (whether your product has quantity in inventory table less than the quantity in stock table) use LINQ queries instead of iterating each collection manually. Here is code that should help you understand the approach (working [example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dzVz8O)):

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int employeeId = 1;
        var storeId = EmployeeList.Single(t => t.EmployeeId == employeeId).StoreId;
        CanAddProduct(1, storeId); // false
        CanAddProduct(2, storeId); // true
    }

    static bool CanAddProduct(int itemId, int storeId)
    {
        var inventory = InventoryList.FirstOrDefault(t => t.ItemId == itemId && t.StoreId == storeId);
        if (inventory == null)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("No such product in inventory");
        }
        var stock = StockList.Where(st => st.ItemId == itemId &&
            st.Quantity < inventory.Quantity && st.StoreId == storeId);

        if (stock.Any())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You can't add ItemId={0}. You have The minimum stock", itemId);
            return false;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("You can add ItemId={0}", itemId);
        return true;
    }
}
```